# Adding and Removing Loggers at runtime in log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I am adding loggers at runtime in log4j.xml

```
<logger name="com.bas">    
       <priority value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="B2BAPP"/>
</logger>
```

my java code for loding runtime log4j.xml

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4j.xml,100000L);
```

Getting loggers at runtime in java code through:

```
Enumeration enumLoggers = 
      Logger.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository().getCurrentLoggers();
```

When I am adding logger to the log4j then I get the logger name in **enumLoggers** but if I remove any existing loggger (like removed logger "com.bas") then its not getting removed from enumLogger even after the specified time delay (ie 100000L in this case).

May I know why? Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the `XMLWatchdog` class (and its super class) reveals that it does not call `LogManager.resetConfiguration()`, so perhaps this is the reason? It's probably meant to work "incrementally".